# Phantomjs windows path is set but still can't run from cmd prompt

Tags: windows, phantomjs, system-variable

[image]

The above image is a snippet i took from my `Path` system variable. however whenever i attempt to run `phantomjs` i get the following message:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what i might be missing?

Comment: Have you reopened the Command Prompt window after adding PhantomJS folder to PATH? Also I kind of don't recognize that dialog, what Win version is it in? Could you show more of that window?

Comment: @Vaviloff That works (closing the cmd prompt and starting again)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should close and reopen Command Prompt after changing PATH variable for the changes to take effect.